# Order function doing something I dont understand

Tags: r

I am trying to order the data frame in descending order using the order function but when I do it removes all but a handful of the variables. Why doesnt the function work and why is it removing most of the data frame. Thanks for any help!

```
library(Lahman)

Batting_61 <- Batting[Batting$yearID >= 1960 & Batting$yearID <=1969,]


HR_61 <- aggregate(Batting_61$HR~Batting_61$playerID, data = x, FUN = sum)
colnames(HR_61) <- c("PlayerID","HR")
HR_62 <- HR_61[order(-HR),]
```

Comment: What is `HR`? I assume you have a variable of that name which is the length of the data set you get returned (i.e. shorter than your data.frame).

Comment: A few problems I can see. 1. `x` is not defined anywhere in the `aggregate` function. Did you mean to use `Batting_61`? 2. No need to change the column names. 3. you need to put HR_61$HR in the `order` function.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this work?

```
Batting_61 <- Batting[Batting$yearID >= 1960 & Batting$yearID <= 1969,]
HR_61 <- aggregate(Batting_61$HR~Batting_61$playerID, data = x, FUN = sum)
colnames(HR_61) <- c("PlayerID","HR")
HR_62 <- copy(HR_61)    

HR_62 <- HR_62[order(HR_62$HR, decreasing = TRUE),]

      PlayerID  HR
857  killeha01 393
1    aaronha01 375
1045  mayswi01 350
1373 robinfr02 316
1058 mccovwi01 300
752  howarfr01 288
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're maybe trying to do is this below, but I made it using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(Lahman)

Batting %>% 
  filter(between(yearID, 1960, 1969)) %>% 
  group_by(playerID) %>% 
  summarise(HR = sum(HR)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(HR))

#> # A tibble: 1,786 x 2
#>    playerID     HR
#>    <chr>     <int>
#>  1 killeha01   393
#>  2 aaronha01   375
#>  3 mayswi01    350
#>  4 robinfr02   316
#>  5 mccovwi01   300
#>  6 howarfr01   288
#>  7 cashno01    278
#>  8 bankser01   269
#>  9 mantlmi01   256
#> 10 cepedor01   254
#> # … with 1,776 more rows
```